# How to use absolute URLs with @use in Sass?

Tags: sass

Is there any way to `@use` absolute URLs in Sass?

Like in CSS:
`@import url("http://...")`

I want to avoid using `@import` in Sass since it won't be supported much longer.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why do you think that `@import` will not be supported?

Comment: It's discouraged per official documentation with the notice that's it will be discontinued in the future https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Comment: from https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use `The simplest @use rule is written @use "<url>", which loads the module at the given URL`

Comment: I've tried it like that (```@use "https://..."```) but I get a compiling error saying the resource couldn't be found.